# How to convert time.Now() object to string and vice versa in Golang?

Tags: string, date, go, time, utc

converting time.Now() to string is easy just do time.Now().String().
How to do the reverse part??

ex if time.Now.String() is "2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001", how to convert this string to time.Time() object

Comment: Use time.Parse.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something along these lines, but the `layout` and `str` values will need to be modified to properly reflect the format you're using.

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
str := "2014-11-12T11:45:26.371Z"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)
```

The `layout` value tells Golang what the format of the date is expected to be, whereas `str` is your date value "2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001"